# how to calculate number using SherlockFragment

Tags: actionbarsherlock, fragment, calculator

Hi I am Trying To calculate number like Calculator. the code is working if I use Activity but doesn't work in Sherlock Fragment. I use android:onClick="". Can someone tell what should I do to implement this code. Thank you.

Code :

```
public class Calculate extends SherlockFragment {

private int resultspinner, inputnumber, totals;

private Spinner spinner;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_summary,
            container, false);

    setSpinnerContent(rootView);        
    return rootView;
}

private void setSpinnerContent(View view)
{
  spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById( R.id.spinner );
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity()
          .getBaseContext(),
            R.array.pangkat_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinner.setAdapter( adapter );

 ...
    }

      // showing a toast on selecting an item 
      //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

  });
}

public void startcalculate(View view) {

    EditText ed_resultspinner = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
    EditText ed_input = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
    EditText ed_total = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EditText3);

    try {

        resultspinner = Integer.parseInt(ed_resultspinner.getText().toString());
        inputnumber = Integer.parseInt(ed_input.getText().toString());
        totals = resultspinner + inputnumber;
        ed_total.setText(String.valueOf(totals));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

> ```
> <Spinner
>     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/editText1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:inputType="number" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/editText2"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:inputType="number" >
>  <requestFocus />
> </EditText>
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/editText3"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:inputType="number" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/button1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:onClick="startcalculate"
>     android:text="Button" />
> ```
>
> Error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method startcalculate(View) in the activity class com.user.learing.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because your SherlockFragment class not finding reference onClick for some reason, you have to do is delete the onClick from layout and sets the code manually like this

```
    Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) { 
             // your logic
        }  
    });
```